# custom rules in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I am bit new to jquery can some one help me with defineing rules in jquery in my case

I have defined three field input boxes for phone number nameing them

areaCode
exchange
number

```
<div class="pad10Top"><input name="areaCode" id="mobilePhone1" maxlength="3"/><input name="exchange" id="mobilePhone2" maxlength="3"/><input name="number" id="mobilePhone3" maxlength="4"/><a href="javascript: void(0)"><img name="link" id="linkMobilePhoneBtn" name="link" src="images/theme/btn_clear.gif" class="inlineButton" onclick="$('#mobilePhone1').val('');$('#mobilePhone2').val('');$('#mobilePhone3').val('');"/></a></div>
```

and I would like to design them such that if you type in number in areacode or in exchange or in number you have to type in the values in the rest for the fields for that I wrote the code like this

```
rules: {
            areaCode: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            exchange: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            number: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 4
            }
        },
```

for this I even tried some thing like

```
rules: {
            areaCode: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 3,
            required: "#exchange:filled"
            },
            exchange: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 3,
            required: "#number:filled"
            },
            number: {
                digits: true,
                minlength: 4,
            required: "#areaCode:filled"
            }
        },
```

but if i try this change this is totally failing my validation iam not sure if this is a syntax problem or if my idea is wrong if some one can help me with this It will be so helpful to carry on with my work thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with validation. You can however register an event listener for the blur event on the fields an do your switch there.

Comment: can you show me the sample code if that was the way sorry I am fresher

Comment: You can use the blur event as follows:
`$('#id').blur(function(){
    //your code here
})`

To add a validation message you can use the showErrors() method of jQuery validation. Documentation can be found at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors#errors

Comment: is that going to look some thing like this please let me know I am so new for this 
$('#mobilePhone1').blur(function()
{ 
<input name="exchange" id="mobilePhone2" maxlength="3"/>
}
) can you tell me how this onblur logic works

Comment: so are you guys are so sure that this can not be done by jquery rules?